# Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens - MySQl

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

A better title might be "I can't count" :-(

What's wrong with this code? It should be glaringly obvious, but I can't see it for looking at it.

```
if (isset($_GET['campaign_id']))
{
    ChromePhp::log('API: request to update existing campaign "' . $campaignTitle . '"');
    $sqlCommand = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE campaigns SET title=:title, description=:description, start_time=:start_time, end_time:end_time) WHERE (customer_id=:customer_id) AND (campaign_id=:campaign_id)');
    $sqlCommand->bindParam(':campaign_id', $_GET['campaign_id']);
}
else
{
    ChromePhp::log('API: request to add a new campaign "' . $campaignTitle . '"');
    $sqlCommand = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO campaigns (customer_id, title, description, start_time, end_time) VALUES(:customer_id, :title, :description, :start_time, :end_time)');
}

$sqlCommand->bindParam(':customer_id', $customerId);
$sqlCommand->bindParam(':title', $campaignTitle);
$sqlCommand->bindParam(':description', $campaignDescription);
$sqlCommand->bindParam(':start_time', $startTimeStamp);
$sqlCommand->bindParam(':end_time', $endTimeStamp);
$sqlResult = DatabaseCommand($sqlCommand);
```

Browsing to

```
http://localhost/api/addCampaign.php?customer=1&title=t&description=d&startTimeStamp=1443313713&endTimeStamp=1443313713&campaign_id=5
```

Gives `Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

The browser's developer console log shows `API: request to update existing campaign "t"`.

Who is going to put me out of my misery & make me say "D'oh!" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.  I have no idea why you would get *that* message, but you have this snippet in the `update`:

```
end_time:end_time
```

This should be

```
end_time = :end_time
```

Perhaps that will fix your problem.